# Where can I visit Anthony Howe's amazing wind-powered kinetic sculptures?

Tags: usa, sightseeing, where-on-earth, artworks, washington-state

Mesmerized by [Anthony Howe's incredible kinetic sculptures](http://www.thisiscolossal.com/2016/01/hypnotic-new-kinetic-sculptures-by-anthony-howe/), I wish to see them in real life to appreciate their 3D structure:

[image: In Cloud Light]

Besides [Washington's Orcas Island](http://www.atlasobscura.com/places/howe-art), where can I see them?

[image: Octo]
[image: Olotron]

What are the visiting hours, admission fees, etc, including those at Washington's Orcas Island?

[image: About face]
[image: In-out quotient]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Locations of Public Sculptures:

**USA**

- Spine Tower, San Francisco, California
- Azlon I, Baltimore, Maryland
- Oblongata, Procter & Gamble Hdqts, Mason, Ohio
- Chief II, Tulsa, Oklahoma
- Octo - Greenville, South Carolina
- Lucea I, Elm St, Dallas, Texas
- Cups, Olympic Apartments, 2nd Ave, Seattle, Washington
- Axiom Dyno Trilobyte, Bellingham, Washington
- In Cloud Light IV, Bellevue, Washington
- Fern Pull II, Washington DC
- Azlon Study, Cheyenne, Wyoming

**Canada**

- Fern Pull I aka Shidahiku, Montreal

**South America**

- In Cloud Light III, (Olympic Cauldron), Rio de Janeiro, Brazil

**Europe**

- Vento di Sella, Arte Sella, Valsugana, Italy
- Armadillo, Moscow, Russia
- Kadupul, Istanbul, Turkey

**Asia**

- Trefoil, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia
- In Cloud Light, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia
- Octo III, Dubai, UAE
- Octo I, Dubai, UAE
- Strobe, Dubai, UAE

Comment: Thanks! Hope you don't mind my classifying them by location.

Btw, are you *THE* Anthony Howe? If so, amazing sculptures you've made, sir!

Comment: I'll have to check out the one in Dallas if I ever make it back to work in person.  Great list.

Answer (score 15):

The artist states that he installs and tests most of his works prior to putting them up for sale.  If you're *that* big of a fan, I would suggest emailing him to see if he would be open to you visiting to see any current projects he has installed.  He might not want to do give you a full tour of his studio, but he might be OK with you swinging by to check out his "yard".  He may also be able to give you a list of public installations for recent works.

The worst that can happen is he ignores you or says no to your requests, but asking certainly won't hurt anything.

Note that Mr. Howe lives on Washington's Orcas Island, so you will certainly be able to see the public works there even if you can't see the works in progress.

Comment: Interesting and makes sense, but doesn't exactly answer the questions (where, and visiting info). +1 for good effort anyway.

Comment: @Gnubie, Edited to add Mr. Howe's location.  I didn't realize I left that out.

Comment: Thanks, JPhi1618. My link in the question already states Orcas Island, btw. I'm torn on which of the 2 answers to accept, so I'll let democracy speak and accept the more upvoted one, though Karlson's actually gives a location besides Orcas Island.

Answer (score 7):

You will need to do quite a bit of clicking and reading on [HoweArt.net](http://www.howeart.net) but you can find some pieces outside Orca Island like:

- [OCTO 3](http://www.howeart.net/ImageHTML/OCTO3.html) - Installed at City Walk Mall on Al Safa St., Dubai

Quite a few others have been sold but currently not indicating where they have been installed.

Answer (score 3):

An Octo 2 sculpture is at the corner of McBee and Falls in Greenville, South Carolina:

http://google.com/maps?q=34.8491,-82.3981&t=h

[image: http://youtu.be/mnPz5qLnzpo]

More info:

http://www.greenvilleonline.com/story/news/local/2014/09/27/qamy-makes-spinning-sculpture-spin/16268515/